# Is Sortable compatible with Symfony 4.2 (using stof/doctrineExtensionsBundle)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

I am using stof/doctrineExtensionsBundle v1.3 with Symfony v4.2.4, having some trouble setting up the Sortable extension. I have installed the bundle using Symfony flex:

```
composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle
```

After that I activated Sortable in config\packages\stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml, as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/configuration.html#activate-the-extensions-you-want):

```
// config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            sortable: true
```

I have got an Entity named PhotoSeries which I have already rigged with @SortablePosition and @SortableGroup:

```
// Entity/Portfolio/PhotoSeries.php

...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=8)
 * @Gedmo\SortablePosition
 */
private $position;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PhotoAlbum", inversedBy="series")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_album", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Gedmo\SortableGroup
 */
private $album;

...
```

The actual update of sorting positions is now done by an ajax call to the following controller method:

```
// src/Controller/BackendImageryController.php

...

/**
 * @Route("/series/sort/{id}/{newPosition}", name="sort_series", requirements={ "id": "\d+", "newPosition": "\d+" }, defaults={"id":0, "newPosition":0}, methods={"PATCH"}, condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()")
 * @param int $id
 * @param int $newPosition
 * @return Response
 * @throws
 */
public function ajaxSortSeries($id, $newPosition)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $series = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(PhotoSeries::class)
        ->find($id);

    $series->setPosition($newPosition);

    $em->persist($series);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('true');
}
```

Unfortunately, when I look into the Doctrine part of the Symfony Profiler of that call, it only does the following:

```
...

SELECT MAX(p0_.position) AS sclr_0 FROM photo_series p0_ WHERE p0_.id_album = ?
(Parameters: 6)

START TRANSACTION

UPDATE photo_series SET position = ? WHERE id = ?
(Parameters: 0, 6)

COMMIT
```

And that's all, no updating of the other entities (within the same SortableGroup). Am I missing something important or may it be a compatibility issue with Symfony 4.1?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Why do you persist an already persitend entity? you can remove that. Do you use the SortableRepository? @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Sortable\Entity\Repository\SortableRepository")

Comment: The $em->persist() is not necessary in this case, I know. I just put it in for clarification. I do not use the SortableRepository right now – maybe later, if I need some of its methods.